# Using the 12 hour time display option, how can I schedule a mailing to go out at 1 minute past midnight?

Tags: civimail, scheduling

I like to use the 12 hour time display option to set and present times. In most cases it is simply more easily understood.

On a number of occasions it's been important to carefully schedule the timing of a mailing, for example to coincide with the lifting on an embargo on a press release issued by a third party. These can commonly be embargoed until 00:01 on a given date. Id like to set the timing for a mailing to go out at 00:01, but as far as I can tell the field won't accept '00' as the hour value. What time should I set in this field to represent 1 minute past midnight?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you schedule the time you should set to 12:01AM. Initially the time display doesn't display AM/PM but once you begin to enter a time it should show and be editable.

Comment: Many thanks for the answer. I'm sure it's right and I'll check it out, but surely I can't be alone in thinking that this is illogical? i.e. if midnight is 1 hour after 11:00PM then that must mean that midnight is 12:00PM. But no, its 12:00AM, which means noon must 12:00PM? Crazy.

Comment: One more thing is to make sure you schedule for the next day. So 1 hour after 11PM on Tuesday is 12:00AM on Wednesday.